# Values does not refresh in a Blazor view from async call

Tags: c#, blazor

We have a Blazor view with two lists: nodes and services.

The counts of both are displayed.

Those lists are populate from two async GET call in OnInitializedAsync method.

Does someone has an explanation why the third scenario kept displaying Count: 0 even after those GET have been completed?

I thought the second and third scenarios was the same.

Thank you

```
    // success - sequential
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        nodes = await service.GetNodes().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return task.Result;
        });
        services = await service.GetServicesStatus().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return task.Result;
        });
    }

    // success - parallel
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                nodes = await service.GetNodes();
            }),
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                services = await service.GetServicesStatus();
            })
        });
    }

    // fails
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                service.GetNodes().ContinueWith(task => nodes = task.Result);
            }),
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                service.GetServicesStatus().ContinueWith(task => services = task.Result);
            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: Somewhere you need to await or `Wait()` the task which `ContinueWith()` returns. The `ContinueWith` chains the tasks, but it isn't never checked when it's ready.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen you are right, it works, but I was expecting the await for the Task.WhenAll will wait for all the task in the array?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ho, I understand now, it is tasks inside of tasks because of the Task.Run + Fetch, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution for third scenario, your inner most async call is running on a different thread than the UI thread, so you need to refresh UI once inner async call is completed, StateHasChnaged works when UI is fully rendered, so you need to use OnAfterRenderAsync event

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                service.GetNodes().ContinueWith(task =>{
                    Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        nodes = task.Result;
                        // Refresh UI
                        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    });
                });
            }),
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                 service.GetServicesStatus().ContinueWith(task =>{
                    Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        services = await service.GetServicesStatus();
                        // Refresh UI
                        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Surinder Singh!

Comment: [Polite] This may be me being pernickety, but doing task management like this within a component doesn't strike me as good practice.  [And therefore not a practice we should be promoting in an answer on here]  *I'll gladly remove this comment if others disagree.*

Answer (score 1):

As @JeroenvanLangen suggests, your continuations are blocking and block the threads.  Without a clear understanding of the async behaviour of `GetNodes` and `GetServicesStatus` it's hard to answer the *Why*.  But if the results aren't displayed, those tasks haven't completed when the UI does it's final render during the component startup lifecycle.

On the assumption that `GetNodes` and `GetServicesStatus` are just normal async API or data store calls I don't understand why you want to jump threads (with Task.Run) and then block those threads with `Sleep`.

Here's a demo using your first option with no continuations that exhibits the *parallel* behaviour you're looking for.

Basically it runs the two async processes and captures the returned `Task` objects.  It then awaits the completion of both tasks before continuing.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>First: @_first</pre>
    <pre>Second: @_second</pre>
    <pre>Third: @_third</pre>
    <pre>Fourth: @_fourth</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string _first = "Not done yet";
    private string _second = "Not done yet";
    private string _third = "Not done yet";
    private string _fourth = "Not done yet";

    private bool _firstResult;
    private bool _secondResult;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var firstTask = GetFirstDataSetAsync();
        var secondTask = GetSecondDataSetAsync();
        _third = "Startup Completed";

        await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { firstTask, secondTask });

        _firstResult = firstTask.Result;
        _secondResult = secondTask.Result;

        _fourth = "Everthing Completed";
    }

    private async Task GetFirstDataSetAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _first = "First Completed";

        // Here to ensure the UI updates
        await this.AllowUIToUpdate();
    }

    private async Task GetSecondDataSetAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        _second = "Second Completed";

        // Here to ensure the UI updates
        await this.AllowUIToUpdate();
    }

    // Calls StateHasChanged and then yields 
    // This gives the Renderer running on the Synchronisation Context some thread time 
    // to service the Render Queue and update the UI
    private async Task AllowUIToUpdate()
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Yield();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer MrC aka Shaun Curtis!